# How to use regex with cson

Tags: regex, atom-editor, cson

I wanna capture logical operators from ooRexx with regex in a .cson file because I want support syntax highlighting of ooRexx with the Atom editor. Those are the operators I try to cover:

`>= <= \> \< \= >< <> == \== // && || ** ¬> ¬< ¬= ¬== >> << >>= \<< ¬<< \>> ¬>> <<=`

And this is the regex part in the cson file:

```
'match': '\\+ | - | [\\\\] | \\/ | % | \\* | \\| | & |=|¬|>|<|
>= | <= | ([\\\\]>) | ([\\\\]<) | ([\\\\]=) | >< | <> | == | ([\\\\]==) | 
\\/\\/ | && | \\|\\| | \\*\\* | ¬> | ¬< | ¬= | ¬== | >> | << | >>= | ([\\\\]<<) | ¬<< |
([\\\\]>>) | ¬>> | <<='
```

I'm struggling with the slashes (forward and backward) and also with the double `**`My knowledge about regex is very basic, to say it nicely. Is there somebody who can help me with that?

Comment: Try to escape backslashes just once, so that every `\ ` in the operator becomes `\\ ` in the regex. You should also never need `[ ]`. Also state what the actual error is that you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spaces around the pipe bars: these spaces are counted in the regular expression. So when you write something like `| \*\* |`, the double asterisks get caught, but **only** if they are surrounded by a space on each side, and not if they're affixed to a word or at the beginning/end of a line. Same issue with the slashes — I have tested it, and it does seem to catch them for me, but only as long as your slashes (or asterisks) are between two spaces.

A few other things to keep in mind:

- You shouldn't need the square brackets around backslashes; they're useful to provide **classes** of possible characters to match. For instance, `[<>]=` will catch both `>=` and `<=`. Writing `[\\]` is equivalent to writing `\\` directly because `\\` counts as a single character, due to the first escaping backslash. Similarly, your parentheses here are not being used; see [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
- Also think of using [repetition operators](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) like `+` and `*`. So  `\\>+` will catch both `\>` and `\>>`.
- Finally, the question mark will help you avoid repetition, by marking the previous character (or group of characters, in square brackets) as optional. `==?` will match both `=` and `==`.

You can group together a LOT of your statements with these three tricks combined… I'll leave that exercise to you!

Just another hint when developing long regular expressions — use a tester like [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com) or similar with a test file to see your changes in real time, and debuggers like [Regexper](http://regexper.com) will help you understand how your regular expression is parsed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't aware that the spaces are part of the regex pattern. Now I have it working.

Comment: @Atlantaner great! If that worked for you please [mark the question as resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).